# How can I query and filter Firebase Realtime Database

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I would like to get all persons from the database where first name and last name is given by user input.

So far this is my code:

```
admin.database().ref('persons').orderByChild('Firstname').equalTo(firstName).limitToLast(1).once("value").then(function(snapshot) {
}
```

This code works filtering only Firstname, but I cant find any way of adding another Where Clause for Last name. I tried to add another orderBy but it does not seem working. Does the Realtime Database has to be this hard to make a simple query?

Comment: The Firebase Realtime Database queries can only order/filter on a single property. In many cases it is possible to combine the values you want to filter on into a single (synthetic) property, e.g. `"FirstName_LastName": "Frank_van Puffelen"`. For an example of this and other approaches, see my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26700924/query-based-on-multiple-where-clauses-in-firebase

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The short answer: you can't. The long answer: use Google's new [Firestore](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/) database or perform the filtering on the client manually. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26701282/4548500) for other options.

Comment: then I can say whoever made Realtime Database it sucks! thanks for the answer!

Comment: Yes you can...with a custom index. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26700924/query-based-on-multiple-where-clauses-in-firebase

Comment: That's not true, if you read the answer it says you can't. `indexOn` is simply a way to improve read performance when sorting on an arbitrary child.

Comment: @SUPERCILEX If you add a synthetic property to the data, you can accomplish the same use-cases in the realtime database as you can with Firestore. I'm all for recommending Firestore since it makes this a lot easier by managing the composite index for you, but Charlie is right that it **is** possible to filter on multiple values (at least in a simple case such as this one).

Comment: Oh yeah, forgot about that. Still, the question was asking about adding another `equalTo` which isn't possible. In any case, thanks for pointing it out!